# Tensorflow Object Detection Unusually large bounding boxes and wrong results

Tags: tensorflow, bounding-box, object-detection-api

I am building an object detector in TensorFlow to detect, motorbike riders with and without helmet, I have 1000 Images each for riders with helmet, withouthelmet and pedestrians(pu together -- 3000 IMAGES),  My last checkpoint was 35267 steps, I have tested using a traffic video, but I see unusally large bounding boxes with wrong results. Can someone please explain  the reason for such detections? Do I need to wait for atleast 50000 steps?? or Do I need to add datasets(Images in the angle to Traffic Cameras)?

Model - SSD Mobilenet COCO - Custom Object Detection,
Training Platform - Google Colab

Please find the Images attached[Video Snapshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6zBn.png)

[Video Snapshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S6Dr.png)

### Day 2 - 10/30/2018

I have tested with Images today, I have got different results, seems to be correct,2nd Day if I test with single object in a Image. Please find the results
[Single Object IMage Test 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6zBn.png)
[Single Object Image Test 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S6Dr.png)

Tested CHeckpoint - 52,000 Steps

But, If I test with the Images with multiple objects in a road, the detection is wrong and bounding boxes are weirdly bigger, Is it because of the dataset, as I am training with One Motorbike rider(with or with out helmet) per image.

Please find the wrong results

[Multi Object Image Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rqHj.png)
[Multi Object Image Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVKMF.png)

I had also tested with images like all Motorbikes in the scene, In this case, I did not get any results, Please find the Images

[No Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhE8f.png)
[No Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l1Ck.png)

The results are very confusing, Is there anything I am missing?,

Comment: Please also share your `.config` file using for your training. So we can provide better suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to wait till 50000 epocs you should get decent result in 35k or even in 10k. I would suggest

1. go through you data-set again and check all the bounding boxes (data cleaning)
2. Check your model with inference code for changes like batch normalization etc
3. Add some more data with different features, angles and color complexities

I would check these points before going further.

Comment: Thank You @Smit Shilu. I will work on the above suggestions and get back to you.

Comment: Firstly, Can I resize the bigger Images and maintain a relative uniformity on Image sizes and bounding boxes,since some of my images are 920x800 and some are 600x400 ...

Comment: Can you pls share your thoughts on my Day 2 test results.

Comment: It looks like you are not using different dataset of images for training. You are training on some close captured images which gives you very good result but when you try on images taken from above or side it does not work. I would suggest add all kind of images in decent amount and then train again.

Comment: Yes that's a great advice , I have already started preparing Datasets with different angles and we have reduced the Image sizes to 720px as a standard Can you please share your thoughts on the following questions .1) Can I annotate more than one class label in a same picture. Would it be helpful in cases like Motorcycle rider wearing helmet and pillion rider not wearing helmet or Vice Versa?  2) Can I duplicate the same images to increase the dataset size?

Comment: 1) Yes you can and it would be good to do that
2) Yes you can but do some image augmentation like increase gamma or blue it a little etc.